# before :each not executed in shared example

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a test that looks like this:

```
describe "test" do
  shared_example "a thing" do
    before :each do
      puts 'in before'
    end

    describe 'the thing' do
      puts 'in test'
    end
  end

  it_behaves_like "a thing"
end
```

When I run this code, the output is `in test`. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't you forget about `it {}`?

```ruby
describe "test" do
  shared_examples "a thing" do
    before :each do
      puts 'in before'
    end

    describe 'the thing' do
      it 'should puts in test' do
        puts 'in test'
      end
    end
  end

  it_behaves_like "a thing"
end

# output:

  test
    behaves like a thing
      the thing
in before
in test
```